# How do I create a class in AutoHotkey?

Tags: class, autohotkey

I want to create a custom class object for an employee record in AutoHotkey. This class object would store an employee's age, name, and job title.

For example, in Java:

```Java
public class Employee {
    public int age;
    public String name;
    public String title;

    public Employee(int age, String name, String title) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

I would then be able to set properties for new employees.

```Java
Employee worker1 = new Employee(22, "Timothy", "Programmer");
Employee worker2 = new Employee(26, "Anthony", "Quality Assurance");
```

I haven't been able to find anything with equivalent functionality in AHK. From what I can tell, objects in AHK are fairly basic in functionality.

**How do I create a class object with custom properties in AutoHotkey?**

Comment: https://autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm

Comment: [The documentation for objects](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm#Usage_Objects) seems to imply that objects properties can be given properties without needing to declare them beforehand. (i.e. `Employee.Name := "Timothy"`)

Comment: I found a guide which explains AHK's classes from the basics: **[Classes in AHK, Basic tutorial.](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=6033)**

Comment: Can someone update the answer for v2, please? I have tried defining with __new and the class name but both result in the object not being initialised with
either
static repeater := Repeater("Enter")
or 
static repeater := new Repeater("Enter")

Comment: Can't edit the old one. So making another comment. Turns out __new is still correct but one should do without new in the instantiation in V2. However, I am having problems with the static keyword.  If I do it without static, it is fine. As soon as I add static, I get an error about it not having been initialized.

Answer (score 8):

I don't use classes in AutoHotkey, but it should be like so:

```
Class Employee{
    __New(age, name, title)
    {
        this.age := age
        this.name := name
        this.title := title
    }
}

worker1 := new Employee(22, "Timothy", "Programmer")
worker2 := new Employee(26, "Anthony", "Quality Assurance")
```

Comment: It's really an obscure construction to accomplish this, thanks for filling the gaps in the user guides.